# php + replace text inside an array resulting from query

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

this is my approach, with no success anyways, but maybe it gives you an idea of what both my code and coding skills are like, as well as what I am trying to achieve.

---

```
 $data1 = mysql_query("SELECT * from `todolist` WHERE date > '$today' ") 
 or die(mysql_error());

 $data1b = str_replace("text-to-be-replaced", "replaced-text", $data1);

while($info1 = mysql_fetch_array( $data1b )) 
 {
Print "".$info1['thingtobedone'] . " with ".$info1['persontomeet'] . "<br />";
 }
```

---

Also, my approach is incorrect since what I would like to do is set a bunch of search and replace cases.
Something like a list of "search for X and replace for Y" instead of only one replacement. Originally i thought of doing something like "replace A for B and rename array as STEP2", then get array called STEP2 and "search for C and replace it for D, and rename array as STEP3" but...i think this might not be the best way to do so =/

Any recommendations, pointers, corrections will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What column from your `SELECT` statement do you wish to perform the replacement on?

Comment: the return value of "mysql_query" is a resource, not the data you want to search and replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`strtr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) function in PHP to pass in a key => value pair of replacement rules:

```
$data = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM todolist WHERE date > CURDATE()') or die(mysql_error());

// Array of replacement rules. Keys of the array are strings to be replaced.
// Corresponding values of the keys are the replacement strings
$trans = array(
    'stringtoreplace1' => 'replacedstring1',
    'stringtoreplace2' => 'replacedstring2',
    'stringtoreplace3' => 'replacedstring3'
);

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
{
    print strtr($info['thingtobedone'], $trans) . ' with ' . $info['persontomeet'] . '<br />';
}
```

Assuming `thingtobedone` is the column you want to make the replacements on.

Then when you call `strtr($info['thingtobedone'], $trans)`, the function will take the string and replace all occurances of every key value in the `$trans` array with their corresponding values. It's a nice way to make many string-replacements all at once.

Comment: This is great! Exactly what i needed. Also, the explanation provided is very much appreciated too. Ill give it a try and let ya know how it goes! Thanks again!!